# Update specific attribute in row sql server

Tags: sql-server

I need a query to update the users tables. I wrote the one below and it works fine.
But I need to update specific attributes based on what the parameters sent with the Proc, Anyone got any good ideas?

```
--table
 users(userID,firstname,lastName,age,UserTypeID,classID,SectionID)
 --SP

'CREATE Proc UpdateUsers
   (
   @pUserID int ,
   @pFirstName varchar(50),
   @pLastName varchar(50), 
   @pAge int,
   @pUserTypeID int,
   @pClassID int,
   @pSectionID int
  )
   as
    if not exists (select 'true' from Users where UserID=@pUserID)
    begin
print ('operation cannot complete; No such User founded, please enter valid UserID')
return
    end

   if exists (select 'true' from UserTypes where UserTypeID=@pUserTypeID)
   begin
if exists (select 'true' from SectionsClasses where ClassID=@pClassID and 
                         SectionID=@pSectionID)
    update users set FirstName=@pFirstName,  
                             LastName=@pLastName,
                             Age=@pAge, 
                             UserTypeID=@pUserTypeID, 
                             ClassID=@pClassID,
                             SectionID=@pSectionID 

            where UserID=@pUserID
        else
    print ('operation cannot complete; No such Class OR Section founded, please enter valid ClassID AND  DectionID')
end
else
print ('operation cannot complete; No such UserType founded')

GO'
```

Comment: You just add extra parameter(s) and process them using IF clause.

Comment: that will add to much extra code :3

Comment: @abodvdv There is no simpler and more straightforward way of doing this. Are you stubborn or something? `"too much extra code"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`COALESCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) which returns its first non-NULL expression to allow you to pass `NULL` for any values you don't want to update. You `SET` would look like:

```
set FirstName=COALESCE(@pFirstName,FirstName),  
    LastName=COALESCE(@pLastName,LastName,
    Age=COALESCE(@pAge,Age), 
    UserTypeID=COALESCE(@pUserTypeID,UserTypeID), 
    ClassID=COALESCE(@pClassID,ClassID),
    SectionID=COALESCE(@pSectionID,SectionID)
```

As you can hopefully see, if any parameter is `NULL`, we just set the column equal to itself.

Comment: @athabaska - your suggestion may have been interpreted by the OP as "do an if for each possible combination and write a separate UPDATE statement for each one" - which would be too much code for any reasonable number of parameters.